# IDBObjectStore opencursor vs IDBIndex opencursor

Tags: html, indexeddb

In Html5 indexedDB API, there are two ways to search, IDBObjectStore opencursor and IDBIndex opencursor

what are the difference between these two interfaces? which has better performance?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Cursors are the result of a search on your db. The opencursor on the objectstore provides filteribg on the primary key, the opencursor on the index, provides filtering on the keypath of the index.

Performance wise it shouldn't make any difference. For every index a new objectstore is made behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

See Parashuram Narasimhan's performance tests on "Iterations using Cursors/Index Cursors" here:

http://nparashuram.com/IndexedDB/perf/

Very little difference.

Answer (score 1):

IDBObjectStore uses primary key. IDBIndex uses secondary key (index key).

Whether parimary key or secondary key, performance is the same. But key query is significantly faster than (normal) record value query.

Check out my benchmark http://dev.yathit.com/test/perf/crud.html